# fontspec not finding fonts with neither XeLaTeX nor LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, fontspec, texlive, linux, ebgaramond

I've tried so many fonts and none of them work, all I get is:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `ebgaramond.sty' not found.
```

This is an example of what I have on my document, though I've tried many others:

```tex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
```

People have told me XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX would have these fonts with `fontspec` right out of the box, but that doesn't seem to be the case at all.

Here is my current version of XeLaTeX:

```
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 72.1; using 72.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.13; using 1.2.13
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.13.0; using 2.13.0
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 7.1.0; using 7.2.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.39; using 1.6.39
Compiled with pplib version v2.05 less toxic i hope
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.14.2; using 2.14.2
```

And my version of LuaLaTeX:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)
Development id: 7567
```

Is there a command on either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for installing fonts? What am I missing?

Comment: How did you install your TeX installation? I used TeXlive (Windows) and can compile correctly with the `ebgaramond` font, it may have been your installation being minimal perhaps

Comment: You are using a TeX Live package from arch linux. Usually linux distributions split TeX Live into several packages. So you may have to search `ebgaramond.sty` with the file search of your linux package manager to find the corresponding linux package. Often names like `texlive-fontsextra` or something like this is used. Another suggestion would be to install the full TeX Live. Usually there is a package like `texlive-complete` or `texlive-full` to do so.

Comment: Omg, I had installed TeX Live from a weird package because I do remember installing the full version. But right now I tried to do it again with `yay -Syu texlive-full` and it finally works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
luafindfont ebgaramond
```

will show you which Garamond are installed. If the output is empty you have to install the Garamond package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond

And with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond-Regular.otf}
```

you can load Garamond without the *package* `ebgaramond`.

Comment: Indeed. Worth noting that a lot of users install Type1 font packages, possibly out of force of habit, possibly due to online advice that is 10 years out of date. Some OpenType/TrueType fonts do not come with a *.sty file. Others do, for special purposes.